# PreferenceActivity background in ics is gone during scroll

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i'm using PreferenceActivity in my app for settings and when tried to set a background and it looks fine untill the user scroll. during the scroll there is background only below the text (see links to images below)
after the scroll it goes back to how it was before (the way it should look)

the problem happens only on ics (on nexus one it works fine)
did anyone saw that problem before and know how to fix it?
thanks.

thats how it looks before scrolling
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aPKX.png
and thats how it looks during scrolling
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDbgU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the cache color hint to 0

java: getListView().setCacheColorHint(0)
or xml: android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

Comment: i tried that with only 6 0s and it didn't work but with 8 0s it works. thanks :)

Comment: IN FACT (for 2.1 target at least) it does not work AT ALL for any nested Preference screens. No matter what it will change color on scroll. Is there any better way?